# Merging Area objects based on Similar Id

Tags: node.js, database, merge, grouping

I am getting this output :
 "Area":
[{
"AreaId": 2,
"AreaName":xyz,
"Data":
    [{
    "AssetId":somevalue,
        "ActionId":somevalue,
           }]
},
{
"AreaId": 2,
"AreaName":xyz,
"Data":
    [{
    "AssetId":somevalue,
        "ActionId":somevalue,
           }]
}]

But I want it merging to be like this :

```
"Area":[{
"AreaId": 2,
"AreaName":xyz,
"Data":
    [{
"AssetId":somevalue,
"ActionId":somevalue,
  },
 {
"AssetId":someothervalue,
"ActionId":someothervalue,
  }]
```

Comment: I see the same question again today with different username...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupBy` of loadash. Code will look something like this

```
const {groupBy} = require("lodash");

const input = [
  {
    AreaId: 2,
    AreaName: "Bedroom",
    Data: [
      {
        Id: 7,
        AssetId: 1,
        Asset: "TubeLight",
        ActionId: 1,
        Action: "Clean",
        TenantChargeBack: 0,
        TenantChargeType: "%",
        TenantChargeValue: 25,
        Notes: "",
        FilePath: "AWS_Bucket_Name/filename.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    AreaId: 2,
    AreaName: "Bedroom",
    Data: [
      {
        Id: 8,
        AssetId: 1,
        Asset: "Bed",
        ActionId: 3,
        Action: "Repair",
        TenantChargeBack: 1,
        TenantChargeType: "%",
        TenantChargeValue: 50,
        Notes: "",
        FilePath: "AWS_Bucket_Name/filename.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    AreaId: 3,
    AreaName: "Bathroom",
    Data: [
      {
        Id: 9,
        AssetId: null,
        Asset: null,
        ActionId: 2,
        Action: "Replace",
        TenantChargeBack: 1,
        TenantChargeType: "$",
        TenantChargeValue: 100,
        Notes: "",
        FilePath: "AWS_Bucket_Name/filename.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    AreaId: 3,
    AreaName: "Bathroom",
    Data: [
      {
        Id: 10,
        AssetId: 6,
        Asset: "Jaar",
        ActionId: 3,
        Action: "Repair",
        TenantChargeBack: 1,
        TenantChargeType: "$",
        TenantChargeValue: 100,
        Notes: "",
        FilePath: "AWS_Bucket_Name/filename.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    AreaId: 2,
    AreaName: "Bedroom",
    Data: [
      {
        Id: 11,
        AssetId: null,
        Asset: null,
        ActionId: 1,
        Action: "Clean",
        TenantChargeBack: 1,
        TenantChargeType: "$",
        TenantChargeValue: 50,
        Notes: "",
        FilePath: null
      }
    ]
  }
];


const groupedData = groupBy(input, i => i.AreaId);

const result = Object.keys(groupedData).map(j => {
  const combined = groupedData[j];
  return combined.reduce((a, b) => {
    return {
      "AreaId": a.AreaId,
      "AreaName": a.AreaName,
      "Data": a.Data.concat(b.Data)
    };
  })
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```